# Combining date/time and maintaining number formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, importrange

I am using an array formula and IMPORTRANGE to import and combine a date column and time column from another sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(BG1, "FORM-SORT!V:V") & CHAR(10) & (IMPORTRANGE(BG1, "FORM-SORT!W:W")))
```

The first range is my date column and the second is my time column. The data is importing and combining properly, however neither the date nor time is formatting correctly, they are displaying integer values and will not respond to any number formatting options.

Comment: Can you link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(text(IMPORTRANGE(BG1,"FORM-SORT!V:V"),"dd-mm-yy")&CHAR(10)&TEXT(IMPORTRANGE(BG1,"FORM-SORT!W:W"),"hh:mm"))
```